# pandoc header-attributes: Different styles for headers of same level in DOCX output

Tags: ms-word, r-markdown, markdown, pandoc, bookdown

In a *Pandoc Markdown* document, I would assume

```
# My Heading {custom-style='style1'}

Some text ...

# Second Heading {custom-style='style2}
```

to result in the heading "My Heading" having the "style1" and "Second Heading" to have "style2" in *DOCX* (*Word*) output.
However, both headings in the *DOCX* output file simply have the style "Heading 1".

How can I correctly assign "My Heading" to have the "style1"?

Comment: I am unfamiliar with Pandoc and am writing because your question title says "pandoc header-attributes." In Word jargon and structure, there is a profound difference between a header and a heading. You should either modify your question title or provide more information in the question to clarify. My page: https://addbalance.com/word/headersheadings.htm

Comment: Thanks for your comment. The idea of *Pandoc* is to translate between different markups/formats whose underlying design decisions can be different. The term "header-attributes" in my question refers to the nomenclature in the official documentation of *Pandoc*. This is probably most accesible and intuitive for describing the problem.

Comment: Reading the pandoc docs concerning [header attributes](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#heading-identifiers) I don't see a `custom-style` keyword like you're using in your example. Thus, how should pandoc know.about your assumed behaviour. But you maybe could implement it yourself using a Lua filter.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comment. The manual just mentions the more general `key=value` syntax and I did quite a bit of search on the web leading me to the conclusion that using `custom-style` might work (which it does for `div`s and `span`s).